# Ionic 5/Capacitor White Screen that appeard from updating Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5, angular11

For my app, I am using Ionic 5, Angular 11, Firebase, Capacitor.|
My app was working on android before the update.
Angular 11 came out, and my project was running on Angular 9. So I carefully followed instructions on the Angular website about updating Angular. I updated Angular and got a ton of new errors saying my dependencies old. I deleted them and re-installed them. Then, my app started to work on a web browser, and I didn't test it on the phone. I coded some stuff, and it is working well on the web without any error. But when I tried to run it on android, it is not working. I also commented on the new code to test if it is a problem, but it seems the new code is not related to it. Below is all the errors on Android Studio

```html
2021-02-18 21:02:00.640 19834-19834/com.mvider E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-02-18 21:02:00.642 19834-19834/com.mvider E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-02-18 21:02:00.678 19834-19834/com.mvider E/com.mvider: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-02-18 21:02:01.403 19834-19834/com.mvider E/com.mvider: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-02-18 21:02:01.655 19834-19834/com.mvider E/com.mvider: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-02-18 21:02:01.655 19834-19834/com.mvider E/com.mvider: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-02-18 21:02:01.789 19834-19834/com.mvider E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/com.mvider/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
2021-02-18 21:02:03.914 19834-19834/com.mvider E/Capacitor/Console: File: capacitor-runtime.js - Line 361 - Msg: TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
2021-02-18 21:02:03.922 19834-22995/com.mvider E/Capacitor: JavaScript Error: {"type":"js.error","error":{"message":"Uncaught TypeError: fn.bind is not a function","url":"http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js","line":9753,"col":15,"errorObject":"{}"}}
2021-02-18 21:02:03.928 19834-19834/com.mvider E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js - Line 9753 - Msg: Uncaught TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
```

Comment: I would stick with whatever the latest stable version of Angular that `@ionic/angular` uses.

Comment: If you are testing on an android emulator, there is an angular bug on chrome 83, which a lot of emulators use by default. Should be fixed on next angular release.